# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempted to load Config resource 'class path resource [application.yml]'

Tags: java, spring-boot, compiler-errors, illegalstateexception, application.properties

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempted to load Config resource 'class path resource [application.yml]' via location 'optional:classpath:/' but snakeyaml was not found on the classpath
    at org.springframework.boot.env.YamlPropertySourceLoader.load(YamlPropertySourceLoader.java:47)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLoader.load(StandardConfigDataLoader.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLoader.load(StandardConfigDataLoader.java:36)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLoaders.load(ConfigDataLoaders.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataImporter.load(ConfigDataImporter.java:128)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataImporter.resolveAndLoad(ConfigDataImporter.java:86)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentContributors.withProcessedImports(ConfigDataEnvironmentContributors.java:116)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.processInitial(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:240)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.processAndApply(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:227)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:102)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:102)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:87)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:85)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:66)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:120)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:114)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:65)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:339)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:297)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301)
    at com.voicebase.analyticys.MySpringbootMainClass.main(MySpringbootMainClass.java:12)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)
```

The above error is generated everytime i add an application.yml/properties file to my springboot application and try to run it. Although I do not need the application.yml to run my app from intellij, I do want to run the jar file of the same and its causing an issue.

I have tried checking indentation/copy+pasted/manually typed tried everything to correct it but it just doesn't work. I am able to see my application.yml under target folder though.

None of the answers online have yet helped.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.voicebase.analytics</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-vbmedia-tokinesis</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.6</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.18</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.theoryinpractise</groupId>
                <artifactId>googleformatter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <!--                <version>3.1.0</version>-->
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>my.package.MainClassNameApp</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Have you **read** the error? `snakeyaml was not found on the classpath` seems pretty clear. You want to load yaml (optionally) but a dependency to load yaml isn't available.

Comment: But in many other cases this dependency wasn't required to load the yaml. Is it because there might be some other dependency which might be helping in those cases instead of this one?

Comment: Maybe this can help you find the answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26463078/snakeyaml-class-not-found-exception

Comment: That dependency is a requirement to load yaml, without it Spring (Boot) cannot load Yaml. Normally this is automatically included by Spring Boot, you have for some reason decided to change that and exclude it (or included the wrong dependencies). Could you add your `pom.xml` or `build.gradle` to show your dependencies.

Comment: @M.Deinum here u go, added my pom.xml

Comment: Replace `spring-boot-autoconfigure` with `spring-boot-starter` that will pull in more dependencies that are needed. It is the minimal dependency. Finally remove the version tags of your dependencies, those are managed by the `spring-boot-starter-parent`. You also don't need the `maven-compiler-plugin` and `maven-jar-plugin`. All of that is managed by the parent or done by the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` (which you defined twice BTW).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line of your exception tells you exactly what is wrong.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempted to load Config resource 'class path resource [application.yml]' via location 'optional:classpath:/' but snakeyaml was not found on the classpath
```

Especially the partial phrase `but snakeyaml was not found on the classpath`.

If we analyze your `pom.xml` we can see that the error stems from that. You only have `spring-boot-autoconfiguration` as a dependency whereas the minimal useful dependency to use is `spring-boot-starter` as a dpendency. This will pull in the minimal dependencies needed (logging and SnakeYaml to name 2).

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.voicebase.analytics</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-vbmedia-tokinesis</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.theoryinpractise</groupId>
                <artifactId>googleformatter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>            
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

With the above, cleaned up, `pom.xml` it should work. It will pull in the necessary dependencies like SLF4J, Snakeyaml etc. which are needed to run a Spring Boot application.

I also took the liberty to clean the plugins and the configuration thereof and remove some dependencies that are now automatically included.

Comment: @userdr725 if an answer solves your problem, answers the question, you should accept it by clicking the check mark next to the answer.